# Recalculate dy in d3 sankey graph

Tags: javascript, d3.js

The `stroke-width` of the links and the `height` of the nodes are based on dy. I'm guessing the initial dy value gets calculated on initialization and is a function of `data.links.value`.

Here's the structure of my object.

```
graph = {"nodes" : [], "links" : []};
data.links.forEach(function (d) {
graph.nodes.push({ "name": d.source});
graph.nodes.push({ "name": d.target});
graph.links.push({ "source": d.source,
    "target": d.target,
    "value": +d.value,
    "unique": +d.unique,
    "sameday": +d.sameday,
    "sourceNpi": d.sourceNpi,
    "targetNpi": d.targetNpi,
    "sourceName": d.sourceName,
    "targetName": d.targetName,
    "npiname": d.npiname});
});
```

On some user event, I'd like to switch from using `value` to calculate dy to `sameday` or `unique`.

Inside my event handler I'm doing:

```
// set d.value to d.unique
graph.links.map(function(d){
    d.value = +d.unique; 
});

link.data(graph.links, function(d){
        return d.sourceNpi + d.targetNpi;
    })
    .enter().append("path")
    .attr("d", path);
sankey.relayout();
link
    .transition()
    .duration(750)
    .attr("class", "link")
    .style("stroke-width", function(d) {return d.dy; });

var rectTransition = d3.selectAll(".node > rect")
    .data(graph.nodes, function(d){
        return d.name;
    })
    .transition();
rectTransition
    .attr("height", function(d) { return d.dy; })
    .duration(750);
```

Which I expect to recalculate `dy` using `unique` instead of `value` but it's the same value as before the recalculation. Does the data not get re-initialized when I call `.data()`? Is there a way to re-calculate `dy`?

Comment: As a workaround, I'm calculating multiple `graph` objects and when I'm ready to `.transition()` I'll call the new data that calculates `dy` from an alternative value. Also, I was wrong. `dy` is not calculated on `.data()`; rather, it's calculated during `sankey.nodes(NODES).links(LINKS).layout(32)`, more specifically, the `.layout` method, I think.